# Why virtual machines on the same subnet cannot communicate with each other unless through the gateway?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, tap, tun, firecracker

I'm using AWS Firecracker to create two VMs (both have Ubuntu 22.04 OS) on a container that has Ubuntu 22.04 OS. I create a bridge `br0` and assign IP address of `192.168.0.7` to it as the gateway. Then I create `tun/tap` virtual network interfaces for each vm (`tap0` and `tap1`) connected to `br0` and assign IP addresses of `192.168.0.170` (VM1) and `192.168.0.171` (VM2).

I can ping gateway when I'm in each VM and my host can ping both virtual machines. Even VMs have access to internet through the bridge network interface in the host.

The problem is that I cannot ping VM2, when I'm **inside** VM1, unless I remove `192.168.0.0/24` automatically generated routing by the kernel. For example for VM1, I need to remove this:

```bash
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.170
```

By using `ip r del 192.168.0.0/24`, after that I'm able to ping VM2. Note that the `default` routing way is through the gateway `192.168.0.7` in both VM1 and VM2.

I thought that both VMs being on the same NIC is enough for them to be able to ping each other and they don't need to go through gateway. Any idea why it happens? Thanks for your comments and thoughts.