# Should I include gateway IP address in the hostfile to make MPI run?

Tags: mpi, openmpi

I have three virtual machines with IP addresses of `192.168.0.170`, `192.168.0.171`, and `192.168.0.172`. The gateway in the host machine has the IP address of `192.168.0.7`. Due to my problem, described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76222981/10382271), these VMs are only able to ping each other via gateway `192.168.0.7`.

I created a hostfile as:

```
192.168.0.170 slots=2
192.168.0.171 slots=5
192.168.0.172 slots=5
```

And then when I run it by using `mpirun -np 4 --hostfile hostfile echo Hello`, I get this error:

```bash
Open MPI detected an inbound MPI TCP connection request from a peer
that appears to be part of this MPI job (i.e., it identified itself as
part of this Open MPI job), but it is from an IP address that is
unexpected.  This is highly unusual.

The inbound connection has been dropped, and the peer should simply
try again with a different IP interface (i.e., the job should
hopefully be able to continue).

  Local host:          192.168.0.171
  Local PID:           3143
  Peer hostname:       192.168.0.171 ([[46370,1],0])
  Source IP of socket: 192.168.0.7
  Known IPs of peer:
```

In my opinion, this error happens because when `192.168.0.170` as the master node for example wants to communicate with `192.168.0.171`, it sends IP packet through `192.168.0.7` as a middleman. So, since `192.168.0.7` is not listed on the `hostfile`, MPI detects an inbound connection that is not expected.

Any way to avoid this problem? A silly workaround is to include `192.168.0.7` in the hostfile, but it doesn't make sense to me. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The problem here is your gateway does NAT and this is not supported by Open MPI.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet There's no way to get support for NAT in OpenMPI?